# R blogdown: Wrong blog title generated by RSS feed

Tags: html, r, rss, hugo, blogdown

I have succcessfuly created a [blog](https://easystats.github.io/blog/) using blogdown (see its [github](https://github.com/easystats/blog)).

Unfortunately, when [this blogpost](https://easystats.github.io/blog/posts/bayestestr_presentation/) appears on another platform (such as [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/describe-and-understand-bayesian-models-and-posteriors-using-bayestestr/)) through the RSS feed, the "author" seems to be incorrectly displayed.

Indeed, the "author" is shown as "R on easystats", something that I didn't specify anywhere.

Digging a bit more, I discovered that the [RSS feed](https://easystats.github.io/blog/categories/r/index.xml) used had [this template](https://github.com/easystats/blog/blob/master/layouts/categories/rss.xml) with this line:

```
<title>{{ if eq  .Title  .Site.Title }}{{ .Site.Title }}{{ else }}{{ with .Title }}{{.}} on {{ end }}{{ .Site.Title }}{{ end }}</title>
```

I suppose that somehow the title was misspecified in the parameters, however, I have set it up correctly (I think) in the [config.toml](https://github.com/easystats/blog/blob/master/config.toml#L9).

How can I correctly specify the title and all so that it is correctly caught by the RSS feed? Thank you.

Comment: The [RSS feed](http://xmlviewer.scripting.com/?url=https://easystats.github.io/blog/index.xml) currently has the title "easystats". That's what RSS readers will see. Perhaps R-bloggers is adding the "R on" part. Also, your feed needs full URLs, not partial ones.